# Как синтаксически разобрать словосочетание "взяли крепость штурмом"?

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, словосочетания, синтаксический-разбор

Как синтаксически разобрать словосочетание "взять крепость штурмом"? Интересно слово *штурмом*. Если проводить аналогии, то по

> взять крепость **быстро**

*штурмом* является наречием. Но и наречия такого нет. Если же это существительное, то почему в словосочетании

> стричь ёжиком

*ёжиком* является наречием?

Помогите разобраться, запутался.

Comment: А синтаксис здесь при чём? Чистая морфология.

Comment: Морфология?  То есть, из творительного падежа слов "штурм" и "ёжик" были образованы наречия?

Answer (score 3):

Если вы спрашиваете о синтаксическом разборе, то "взяли  штурмом"(завоевали, захватили)- простое глагольное сказуемое, выраженное фразеологизмом.

крепость(кого? что?) -прямое дополнение.

Фразеологизм состоит из глагола взяли + наречия(как? каким образом?)штурмом ( с помощью штурма, натиска, силой, как шторм).

Comment: Не фразеологизм, а устойчивое выражение, которое можно легко распространить : *крепость взяли отчаянным штурмом*.  Да вот пример : Д.И. Иловайский. Краткие очерки русской истории (1860)
"6 ноября пала в Армении первоклассная турецкая крепость
Каре, которую русские ***взяли геройским ночным штурмом***
( генерал Лазавер)."

Comment: Очень грамотно:"Не фразеологизм, а устойчивое выражение". Фразеологизм и есть устойчивое выражение. Фразеологизмы делятся на сращения,единства и фраз.сочетания. Брать/взять штурмом - фразеологическое сочетание, где самостоятельное значение каждого слова обособлено чётко, однако остаётся несвободным. Можно сказать брать/взять штурмом, но нельзя сказать завоевать штурмом, захватить штурмом, это будет избыточно. Эти обороты не являются семантически неделимыми, их можно распространить.

Comment: Он зафиксирован как фразеологизм в Большом толково-фразеологическом словаре Михельсона http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/michelson_new/754/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: Привычное словосочетание, только и всего. Распространяемое, повторюсь. Есть еще одно привычное сочетание, но с обратным порядком слов : "наши войска ***штурмом овладели*** и Днепропетровском и Днепродзержинском!" (Нацкорпус)

Comment: Ну, тогда почитайте теорию о типах фразеологизмов, в частности  о фразеологических сочетаниях, пригодится.

Comment: Зачем нам теория в данном случае? Хватает языковой практики. А Михельсон в свое время записал во фразеологизмы добрую половину обычных русских выражений. Нет, не фразеологизм.

Comment: Во Фраз. словаре русс. лит. языка http://phraseology.academic.ru/ нет такой статьи - брать/взять штурмом. Проверьте сами.

Comment: Если так пойдет дальше, то словосочетание *пошел сдаваться* непременно запишут в поговорки, крылатые выражения и фразеологизмы. Да весь русский язык туда можно впихнуть, сплошь один чистый подтекст кругом, ирония и стеб.

Answer (score 2):

Скажите, а *утром* может являться только словоформой существительного *утро*? Риторический вопрос. Здесь *штурмом* — это наречие образа действия: взять крепость (как? каким образом?) штурмом. Это обстоятельство образа действия с точки зрения синтаксиса. Соответственно, во втором словосочетании *ёжиком* тоже никак не существительное, это опять-таки наречие образа действия.

Comment: Согласно словарю слово *ёжиком* это самое настоящее наречие, такое же как *холодно*, *быстро* и т.д.

Comment: Что за глупость вы несёте, милостивые господа...  В выражении "сразить врага мечом": "мечом" тоже, что-ли, наречие? "Блеснуть яркой звездой"? "Вскипеть гейзером"?  Обстоятельство образа действия, понятно.  Но наречие?...

Comment: Сразить врага (чем?) мечом. Блеснуть звездой ~ блеснуть, как звезда. И так далее. В ваших примерах все существительные. Но взять (чем?) штурмом, пойдем (чем?) утром -- так не скажешь.Здесь наречия.

Comment: А в качестве ***обстоятельства*** может использоваться "ранним утром"?  Или только "рано утром"?

Comment: Niemand, в словаре есть слово "штурмом"? Если нет, то это не наречие, а существительное с обстоятельственным значением. Используйте правильную терминологию. Также некорректно говорить, что штурмом - это не полноценное наречие. Это просто  НЕ НАРЕЧИЕ.

Comment: Вера, штурмом - это наречие, т.к. неизменяемое и обозначает признак действия взять как? штурмом. В Дидактическом словаре П.Червинского   зафиксировано как наречие
https://books.google.ru/books?id=b1fqCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA264&lpg=PA264&dq=%D1%88%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC+-+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=uJXCaiEibk&sig=vbsR_Oes_EEhuZHexPgoyorZLpU&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAmoVChMI__2bgoewyAIVRUIUCh01_gja#v=onepage&q=%D1%88%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC%20-%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5&f=false

Comment: А идти шагом?-тоже не наречие? А в обычном словаре оно(штурмом) и быть не может , только в словаре фразеологизмов, и оно там есть.

Answer (score 1):

Взять крепость штурмом.

Мне кажется, что это обычное словосочетание: брать/взять (что?) крепость (дополнение), взять (как?) штурмом (**обстоятельственное существительное**, или наречное выражение, в форме Т.п., определяющего способ (инструмент)  действия, обстоятельство образа действия, не относится к сказуемому.

Крепость можно взять штурмом или осадой. Непонятно, почему нужно считать это выражение устойчивым.

**Из словаря:** **БРАТЬ,** 7. что. **Овладевать, захватывать**; побеждать, выигрывать (во время войны, политической борьбы, спортивного состязания, охоты и т.п.). Б. крепость, высотку.

Comment: Так называемая *военная лексика*, которая очень быстро входит в повседневную речь. *Если не согласятся, будем брать преподов (чем? лаской? уговорами? ) штурмом*.

Comment: Так вы их будете брать или захватывать,завоёвывать, т.е. брать штурмом?

Comment: Вера, Вам кажется обычным сочетанием со свободной сочетаемостью? Можно сочетать ещё с какими-либо глаголами, кроме взять/брать? Приведите пример!  А вот  Большой словарь русских поговорок считает его поговоркой, т.е. фраз.сочетанием:
http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/49778/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C__%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%88%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC

Comment: Вам что, непонятен смысл высказывания? Студенты будут брать преподов штурмом, если те откажутся идти на компромисс. Не я, студенты.

Comment: Да нет,смысл понятен, а вот сказуемое у Вас "будут брать" или "будут брать штурмом"? Действие-то какое будет совершаться? Брать штурмом - сказуемое. Это и доказывает, что это фразеологизм, как бросить взгляд=посмотреть.Если разберёте как сказуемое бросить - грубая ошибка.

Comment: Это называется вкусовщина. Кто любит попа, а кто - попову дочь. Брать в плен - тоже  фразеологизм, по-вашему?? Так можно дойти до полного абсурда, подумайте над этим внимательно.

Comment: Пример без глаголов брать/взять: "Музыка сменилась металлическим рокочущим голосом диктора Левитана, произносившего в этот момент: "…и штурмом ОВЛАДЕЛИ городом и важным железнодорожным узлом" (Василий Гроссман).